# How to block transfers/restores with RevenueCat SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, revenuecat

In my app, I require all users to create an account and subscribe before using. RevenueCat handles this. However, when a user who does not subscribe signs up/logs in on a users phone who does have an account, the entitlement transfers over to the other account. I want to prevent this. Below is my code that I have, would appreciate if any know knows how to do this:

```
Purchases.shared.purchase(package: pkg) { (transaction, customerInfo, error, userCancelled) in
    if userCancelled {
        print("User cancelled the transaction.")
        return
    }
    
    if let error = error {
        // Handle errors
        print("Error occurred during transaction: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }
    
    if customerInfo?.entitlements.all["All Access"]?.isActive == true {
        // Activate Account
        print("Account is active")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
            authViewModel.isActive = true
            authViewModel.updateSubscriptionStatus(status: authViewModel.isActive)
        }
    } else {
        print("User does not have an active subscription.")
        self.isSpinningViewShown = false
    }
}
```

RevenueCat community told me to “Keep with original app user id”. I am trying to implement this, however, I do not know how to.

Comment: It's not in your code.  It's in RevenueCat config https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/restoring-purchases

Answer (score 0):

This is configured in the RevenueCat dashboard. What you want is **"Keep with original App User ID"**

> If an App User ID tries to restore transactions that are already associated with a different identified App User ID in RevenueCat, you can configure how RevenueCat should respond by changing the dropdown in Project Settings > General in the dashboard:

https://www.revenuecat.com/docs/restoring-purchases#keep-with-original-app-user-id